# Ignoring values from query if a entry is null

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am creating a library database and keeping control of book loans and returns.
I want to be able to check if a return date for a book is null or not. If a return date for a loan entry is null I want to ignore all other entries that book has. 
[Book loan table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7jl7.png)

Each book has an ISBN
If an entry for a ISBN is null, it should ignore all other entries for that isbn.

I've tried everything but i cant seem to get it right :/

Comment: Please replace your photo with according CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTo scripts. Show desired result for shown data strictly in textual table form.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And presumably you only have one copy of each book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a subquery that finds all the ISBN with `NULL`

```
SELECT DISTINCT isbn
FROM library
WHERE fecha_devolucion IS NULL
```

Then use that to filter the entire table:

```
SELECT *
FROM library
WHERE isbn NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT isbn
    FROM library
    WHERE fecha_devolucion IS NULL
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This worked perfectly.